# Razor framework - backend or frontend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What kind of framework is Razor? Is it backend or frontend?
What is the difference between the two types of frameworks?
I'm trying to learn a little bit more about backend and frontend frameworks and since I usually work with Visual Studio Asp.net MVC was wondering about it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a framework . I think you're misinterpreting certain concepts. Razor is a server side view engine, and it uses C # or VB.NET to generate dynamic content.

[Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Answer (score 4):

This question is a couple of years old, but I'm going to add my two cents.

People struggle to give an answer to this question because the terms 'front-end' and 'back-end' aren't formally defined anywhere. Because of that, any answer is purely subjective.

That being said, it is my *opinion* that the relationship between front-end/back-end and client-side/server-side isn't necessarily one-to-one

I think it helps to think of it like this: **client-side and server-side are run-times**, while **front-end and back-end are a separation of concerns**.

'Client-side' always refers to code executing on the client's machine and 'server-side' always refers to code executing on the server. A 'front-end' developer deals with displaying data to the user and getting data from the user, while a back-end developer deals with storing, manipulating, and retrieving that data.

Consider a front-end developer who is tasked with building a UI. Much of the code they write will be the typical HTML / CSS / JS. However, they will also have to deal with the data that is passed to the front-end from the backend. This is where Razor comes into play. The front-end developer will write the Razor code (which executes on the server-side) to display the data.

That is, **the front-end developer will write server-side code to help generate the UI, in addition to writing the client-side code that really defines the UI**.

Now, I can't imagine a scenario where a back-end developer will write client-side code.

So, to answer your question, **Razor is a front-end technology that executes on the server-side runtime**. It's only purpose is to generate the UI, which is the concern of the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Razor is for writing dynamic html page which is front end and c# is for writing backend logic. Although you could move all the backend logic inside razor but its highly not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Razor allows you on the **back-end** more easily create views (.cshtml in C#).
It is more like templating system...

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c